# How to send an image as multipart form object as a parameter to url from ios to spring mvc

Tags: ios, web-services, spring-mvc

How to send an image as Multipart form object as a parameter to url from ios to spring mvc

url which is accepting at the back end in www.test.com?id=test&multipartforObject=

So in IOS how can i convert the image to Multipartform object to pass it as param  along with the URL.

Manjush

Answer (score 0):

In practice, many clients and servers do only support URLs up to a certain length.If you pass image as param along with the URL,sometimes, URL's length maybe to too long.

I suggest using HTTP/POST to upload multipart files.There is some sample code using [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to upload multipart files:

```
NSData * imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] ,0.6);
NSData * imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"] ,0.6);
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:imageData1 withFileName:@"image1.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:@"certImage"];
[request addData:imageData2 withFileName:@"image2.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:@"certImage"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```